# Batch File Commands to Remove File from Removable Drive (virus)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I don't know how to code myself, just managed to find some from Google and try to compile it. But it didn't work as I expected. Recently I've found that there is a virus spreading among my place without the user realizing it. The batch file is supposed to remove the files from the specified drive's `%temp%` folder with the extension `.exe` with exactly 138784 bytes. This the batch file I came up with, it works for removing it from the temporary folder but not for removing the file on their removable drive:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "Enter Drive letter"
set /p letter=
for /r %%f in (*.exe) do if %%~zF EQU 138784 del %%F /f
attrib -s -h -a /s /d %letter%:*.*
c:
cd %temp%
Del wdr201.exe /f
ECHO "Process completed."
Pause
```

Comment: The only action you are performing in relation to their 'drive letter' is to blindly screw with all of it's contents attributes.

Comment: because some of them have their own "removable drive" connect to their machine, it's unlikely that it will be D drive all the time.

Comment: I don't think you understand, you haven't attempted to do anything to any file on the drive allocated to the variable %letter% except for change the attributes of everything. If you want to remove a file it would be a good idea to add a command which does that, (perhaps **DEL** or **ERASE**).

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this code inspired from this one : **[Hackoo_Virus_Cleaner.bat](http://pastebin.com/j0U5fDwn)**

```bat
@echo off
Mode con cols=80 lines=6 & Color 9E
Title Searching the Drive letter of your USB Key and clean *.lnk files by Hackoo 2016
Set TmpLogFile=%tmp%\TmpLog.txt
Set "LogFile=%UserProfile%\Desktop\Hackoo_Virus_Clean_%UserName%_Log.txt"
If Exist %TmpLogFile% Del %TmpLogFile%
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" ^|find /i ":"') do (Set MyUSB=%%i)
cls
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set _drive=%MyUSB%
If Exist !_drive! (
cls
echo.
echo           #########################################################
echo                        Your usb key is connected as !_drive!
echo           #########################################################
echo           Hit any key to remove malicious files and unhide files ...
pause>nul
Cls
echo(
Echo Removing malicious files/unhiding files... Please wait, this may take a while...
del /s /f /q !_drive!\*.lnk>>"%TmpLogFile%"2>&1
Cmd /U /C Type "%TmpLogFile%" > "%LogFile%"
Start "" %LogFile%
attrib -s -h -a -r /s /d !_drive!\*.*
Explorer "!_drive!\"
) ELSE (
cls
color 0C
echo.
echo           #########################################################
echo                         Your usb key is not detected
echo           #########################################################
echo.
)
pause & exit
```

Comment: Hi Sir, i've tested your code but very odd that it only delete 1 file at a time, as in i need to run multiple time if there are more than 1 .lnk file inside the removable drive